# Referencing table with generated primary keys

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to increase the constraint of my **MySQL** database schema adding foreign key constraint to each table.

Table 1: **USERS**

```
    +---------+----------+-------------
    | id      | username | Other fields
    +---------+----------+-------------
    | 1       | John     |
    | 2       | Mark     |
    +---------+----------+-------------
```

> `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Table 2: **DISKS** (This has a **one to many** relationship with **USERS**)

```
    +---------+----------+-----------+-------------
    | id      | id_user  | disk_name | Other fields
    +---------+----------+-----------+-------------
    | 1       | 1        | disk A    |
    | 2       | 2        | disk B    |
    +---------+----------+-----------+-------------
```

> `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`id_user`)
>   INDEX `fk_disks_idx` (`id` ASC)
>
> CONSTRAINT `fk_disks`
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
>
> REFERENCES `database`.`USERS` (`id`)
>
> ON DELETE NO ACTION
>
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Table 3: **FILES**  (This has a **one to many** relationship with **DISKS**)

```
    +---------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------
    | id      | id_disk  | id_user  | file_name | Other fields
    +---------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------
    | 1       | 1        | 1        |           |
    | 2       | 2        | 2        |           |
    +---------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------
```

> `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL
>
> `id_disk` INT(11) NOT NULL
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`id_disk`,`id_user` )
>   INDEX `fk_files_idx` (`id` ASC, `id_user` ASC)
>
> CONSTRAINT `fk_files`
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`id_disk`, `id_user`, `id_user`)
>
> REFERENCES `database`.`DISKS` (`id`)
>
> ON DELETE NO ACTION
>
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Table 2: **FILES_ON_NAS**  (This has a **one to one** relationship with **FILES**)

```
    +-------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------
    | id    | id_files | id_user  | id_disk  | file_name | Other fields
    +-------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------
    | 1     | 1        | 1        | 1        |           |
    | 2     | 1        | 2        | 2        |           |
    +-------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------
```

> `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> `id_files` INT(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL,
>
> `id_disk` INT(11) NOT NULL,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`id_files`,`id_user`,`id_disk` )
>   INDEX `fk_files_on_nas_idx` (`id` ASC)
>
> CONSTRAINT `fk_files_on_nas`
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`id_files`,`id_user`,`id_disk`)
>
> REFERENCES `database`.`FILES` (`id`,`id_user`, `id_disk`)
>
> ON DELETE NO ACTION
>
> ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

## Question:

As you can see the more I reference table in cascade the more primary keys I get. How can I design the database to avoid the replication of primary keys and therefore data duplication as well? Should I delete the auto incremented key for each table? Is it a good practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID of the disk is sufficient to uniquely identify a disk. So there's no reason to include the ID of the user into the disk's primary key. It would even be an extremely bad idea, because that means that if a disk's user changes, you would need to modify the primary key.

Same for a file. A file ID uniquely identifies a file. So there's no reason to add the disk ID into the primary key of a file.

Comment: I totally agree with you. The reason why I am asking this question is because when I use MySQL Workbenck (the EER model section ) to create a one to many relationship which generate the sql file, the software put all primary keys into the table. I tried to delete the unnecessary primary keys but the engine does not allow to forward the model into the database

Comment: I have no idea of how MySQL workbennch works. I generally use PostgreSQL, and I create my tables using SQL directly.

Comment: I've used MySQL Workbench in the past and I don't remember running into this problem... But I'm using SQLYog now so I can't really tell.

Comment: You're probably not doing it correctly since there's no reason it would make a primary key out of a foreign key like that.

Comment: I solved my question just following your best practice. I deleted the fields manually in a gedit document and after pasting it in the mysql console I run the script without issues. Something weird with the software which led me to create unnecessary primary keys

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino, I believe workbench is doing so because you are using "identifying" instead of "non-identifying" relationships.
Also, to be pedantic, it looks to me like DISKS has a many-to-one relationship with USERS, as there is no way a disk can be associated with more than one user.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against deleting the auto-incremented keys.

However you don't need to make a new primary key everytime :

- If you want that multiple users share one disk, just put a *foreign key* of `id_disk` in **USERS**
- If you want that one user can have multiple disks, then put a *foreign key* of `id_user` in **DISKS** instead.

Only use primary keys like that when you face a *Many-to-Many* relationship. In this case, you need to create a new table to join both tables; with the primary keys of both tables as foreign keys making a coupled primary key like you did.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read a little about [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In your case, i would make the [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) `id` the only primary key in the tables. Something like:

```
create table users (
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(50),
    ...,
    primary key (id)
);

create table disks (
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    user_id integer,
    diskname varchar(50),
    ....,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
);
```

For `files` you are going to have to answer the question: does file ownership depend on the file directly, or transitively on the disk ownership, or are the ownerships independent? A file owned by John on a disk owned by Jack? Seems ok to me, but your domain might have different rules. In that case, drop the user_id from the files table (otherwise your database won't be in [Third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)).

```
create table files (
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    disk_id integer,
    user_id integer, -- you have to decide whether this is necessary
    filename varchar(50),
    ....,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (disk_id) references disks (id),
    foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
);
```